# Get records within a specific timeframe in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.1

On my website, I use Laravel's `created_at` to store the time at which images are uploaded.

However, I want to be able to create a query that gets images only within a specific time frame.

Those would be:

-The past 24 hours

-The past week

-The past month

-The path year

I was thinking of something like...

```
$images = Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->hours(24))->get();
```

It would be easy to get records from within specific hours, since I could simply go from 24 to 168 to 672 to 2087 (day, week, month, year).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sub`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) methods:

```
Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();
Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subWeek())->get();
Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())->get();
Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYear())->get();
```

Or:

```
Images::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->get();
```